# unable to get images to show up using iText7 HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf

Tags: c#, itext7

I am trying to merge a large amount of html files that are generated into one pdf file.  I am able to make the pdf file successfully but the images are not showing up.

The img tags src attribute contains "../..", which I read does not work with iText7.

I took a small set of files and edited the "../.." out of the img tags, then moved the images to a folder under the html files, and that work correctly.

I tried overriding the attribute but the images still do not show up.  I have validated that the updated src is correct.  See code below:

in the main function

```
            ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
            properties.SetTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DestinationFolder + "\\" + outFileName);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);         
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);

            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading File: {0}", filename);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
                Stream htmlReader = new FileStream(SourceFolder + "\\" + filename, FileMode.Open);
                    
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlReader, temp, properties);
                temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(baos.ToArray())));
                merger.Merge(temp, 1, temp.GetNumberOfPages());
                temp.Close();
                htmlReader.Close();

            }

            pdf.Close();

    class CustomTagWorkerFactory : DefaultTagWorkerFactory
    {
        public override ITagWorker GetCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context)
        {
            if ("img".Equals(tag.Name(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tag.GetAttribute("src"));

                return new UpdateImgTagWorker(tag, context);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

        public override void ProcessEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context)
        {
            IAttributes attributes = element.GetAttributes();
            var sourceAttribute = attributes.GetAttribute("src");
            sourceAttribute = sourceAttribute.Replace("../..", imageFolder);
            sourceAttribute = sourceAttribute.Replace("/", "\\");
            attributes.SetAttribute("src", sourceAttribute);

            Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("src"));
            base.ProcessEnd(element, context);
        }
```

I have tried downloading the image in the ProcessEnd function but cant figure out how to save it back to the element.  I also don't see a way to override ProcessContent.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

As these html files are autogenerated I really don't want to have to modify the files every time I need to generate the pdf.